# Is the number of non-commutable pairs always a multiple of the group size?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $s$ be the number of pairs $(x/y)$ $x,y\in G$ with $xy\ne yx$.

> How can I prove that $s$ is a multiple of $|G|$ (If $G$ is abelian, we have $s=0$ ) ?

I thought about proving that the number of pairs $(x/y)$ with $xy=yx$ , where $x=y$ is possible is a multiple of |G| , which is obviously equivalent to the given claim. But I was not successful.

I did not find a counter-example with GAP upto $|G|=255$.

Comment: You asked a question and many peaple gave asnwer. Why do not you give any reaction ?

Comment: Moos 's anwer is enough clear. I also exactly computed the "number". Which part is not clear for you. I used Burnside Lemma to make  answer clear for anyone without doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denote the Centralizer of $x$ (the elements that commute with $x$) by $C_x$.

Let $G = B_1 \cup \dotsc \cup B_n$ be the conjugation orbits of $G$.

For $x,y$ in the same orbit - say $B_1$ - we have $|C_x|=|C_y|=\frac{|G|}{|B_1|}$, i.e. the number of non-commutung pairs $(a,b)$ with the first entry $a$ contained in $B_1$ is

$$\sum_{a \in B_1}(|G|-|C_a|)=|B_1| \cdot (|G|-\frac{|G|}{|B_1|}) = |G|\cdot (|B_1|-1),$$

a multiple of $|G|$. We can do this for each orbit and get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: fix $x$ and look at the set of all $y$'s that don't commute with $x$. Then sum over all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can directly find this number.

Set of all pairs: $\{(x,y)|x,y \in G\}$ is $|G|^2$. Now let's compute

set of commuting pairs $(x,y)$. It is equal to $$\sum_{g\in G}(C_G(g))$$.

By Burnside Lemma, $$\sum_{g\in G}(C_G(g))=|G|k$$
 where $k$ is the number of the conjugacy classes. Hence,

$$s=|G|^2-|G|k=(|G|-k)|G|$$.

Comment: This was already in my answer. Sum up my result for all orbits and you get (of course) precisely the same number.

Comment: @MooS: I do not see this conclusion in your answer and I directly used Burnside Lemma to reach conclusion. My answer is clearly different from yours.

Comment: @MooS: By the way you wrote that when we sum we get precisly same number. Is it something unexpected ?